# How to implement message delivered notification iOS delivery receipt

Tags: chat, ios11

I am developing a messaging application for iOS where I want to show message delivered and read by the user status on the app. same one is like whatsapp. the app will show one tick mark when delivered to the server and two tick mark when the message is sent to the destination from the server.

How surprised I was that application: didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called when app is not active!

Is it really impossible to track message delivery without user interaction when app is not active? Others have suggested keeping log of messages on server and sending them when app opens, but this still requires user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Use an enum for message status.
enum msg_status
{
   case sent,
   case received,
   case seen
}

To get the reachability status of message you can use your sever response.
If message send successfully, show one tick. Set your status variable to .sent

To get two ticks, use Notification success response.
If notification was successfully delivered by your server, set the status variable to .received.

To get blue ticks similar to WhatsApp, use a function such as msg_seen(userId: Int).
Call the function on viewDidAppear() method of your Message ViewController and in body of the msg_seen() method update the status to .seen